# Spell Check for Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, spelling

I have visited a lot of Q/A and Forum sites similar to this one. Many of them however had spell check. I don't see it as a must fix for the site; however if an automated engine/plugin could check the spelling of questions and answers, it could be beneficial to the users and outsiders of this site.

People love spelling and grammar more than anything, as long as it makes sense. 
For instance, if someone says

> > My ***fhate*** is with you, technology.
> >
> > My ***fate*** is with you, technology.

This may be a crummy example, but one letter can change the way someone looks at a question. Without the fate below it, you would think  he meant to type hate, not fate.

Or how about some grammar and format differences.

> ***I am having an issue and I need it fixed soon.***
>
> ***I AM HAVING AN ISSUE AND I NEED IT FIXED IMMEDIATLEY!***

They're little things that won't affect it much. These can change the way people view, the user, the site, the community. People are going to want to figure out answers on a site they can trust. Without spell-check people will think this site is not trustworthy even though it is.

I am not saying you have to, but take it into consideration.

It's your fhate.

Comment: Irony alert: your question title is misspelled.

Comment: My point exactly, that is what auto correct is for or spell check. I am not complaining but to make sure I would like to see the question so I am confirmed, no problem, right?

Comment: My browser does the spell checking for me; and auto-correction is **really** not going to work, not with programming languages and questions about detecting spelling mistakes (with examples of deliberate mistakes) being posted.